# QuillJS: Cannot register a custom class attributor

Tags: javascript, quill

My project is using QuillJS. I'm trying to add a custom class attributor. I want my links to be able to have either no class name, or a class name "custom-link". Having read the documentation here https://github.com/quilljs/parchment#class-attributor I have written this code:

```
const Parchment = Quill.import('parchment');
const CustomLinkClass = new Parchment.Attributor.Class('custom-link', 'custom-link', {
  scope: Parchment.Scope.INLINE
});
Quill.register(CustomLinkClass, true);
```

However when I insert `<a class="custom-link" href="https://google.com">Hello</a>` into the editor, the class name is stripped. Can anybody please help?

There is a Quill Playground example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoPVxO

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the source code of the [Parchment Attributor Class](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment/blob/master/src/attributor/class.ts#L23), this kind of attributor use also a value to create the class. So the final class name should be of the form `class-value`. If you want to achive a single value class attribution, you maybe have to extend the base [Parchment Attributor](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment/blob/master/src/attributor/attributor.ts) and make your own attributor, or use a whitelist to allow only one value. Or you can do like quill do for his classes, by prefixing all your classes (`ql-align-center`, `ql-video`, `ql-color-red` and so on).

```
const Parchment = Quill.import('parchment');
const PrefixClass = new Parchment.Attributor.Class('prefix', 'prefix', {
    scope: Parchment.Scope.INLINE,
    whitelist: [ 'custom-link', 'another-class' ]
});
Quill.register(PrefixClass, true);
```

By doing so, it allows you to use the classes `prefix-custom-link` and `prefix-another-class`. Quill will recognize and keep them.

You can also pragmatically add one of this class to your selection like this: `quill.format('prefix', 'custom-link');`

Answer (score 0):

try to use these lines of code.

```
const Parchment = Quill.import('parchment');
const config = {
  scope: Parchment.Scope.BLOCK
};
const Class = new Parchment.ClassAttributor('class', 'custom', config);
Quill.register(Class, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
const CustomLinkClass = new Parchment.Attributor.Class('custom-link', 'class', {
  scope: Parchment.Scope.BLOCK
});
```

because the Class Attributor takes these parameters:

```
(attrName: string, keyName: string, options?: AttributorOptions | undefined)
```